# how to change code to finish aggregation in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have a book list in json as following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1"),
    "author" : [
        "Mary",
        "Tony"
    ],
    "booktitle" : "Book1",
    "Category" : "Children"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("2"),
        "author" : [
            "Joe",
            "Tony"
        ],
        "booktitle" : "Book2",
        "Category" : "Children"
}
{
            "_id" : ObjectId("3"),
            "author" : [
                "Joe",
            ],
            "booktitle" : "Book3",
            "Category" : "comedy"
}
.......
```

I hope to get the number of authors that have publish books in exactly two different Categories.

Take above example:
Mary has book just in "Children", Tony has books just in "children", Joe has books in "Children" and "comedy". Thus, I hope to get the number 1 because Joe is the only person who publishes book in to different categories.

I write following code in mongoDB, but don't know how to fill the match part:

```
db.collection.aggregate([     
{ $match:{ }},     
{ $project:{ _id:0, author:1 }},     
{ $unwind:"$author" },     
{ $group:{ _id:null, count:{ $sum: 1} }}  
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your aggregation pipeline:

- You want to count categories taking *all* documents into account, so there should be no $match in the beginning.
- You need the category-field, so you need to put it into your initial projection
- You want to group by author, so the author needs to be part of the `_id` of your $group.
- When the author has three books in one category, you want to count it as one category, not three. That means you need to use $addToSet in your $group to generate an array of unique categories per author.
- You then filter the results *after* counting them. That means you need to perform the $match at the end. The thing you want to match on is the size of the array of unique categories.
- And then you finally $group by null to get the total number.

This is how your aggregation should look (untested):

```
     db.collection.aggregate([
         { $project:{ _id:0, author:1, Category:1 } },     
         { $unwind:"$author" },     
         { $group:{ _id:"$author", categories:{ $addToSet: "$Category"} } },
         { $match: { categories: { $size: 2 } },
         { $group:{ _id:null, count:{ $sum: 1} }}  
     ])
```

Comment: I try to use this method, but it fails. it gives me the error: "Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in." there may be better ways to write the code... Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @cacao There is a limit of 100MB for a $group-stage. I didn't thought you would have that much data. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069601/how-to-aggregate-on-huge-array-in-mongodb#26069792 for what is meant with "Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in".