# allowDiskUse not working in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I have data stored in MongoDB in the following format.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("570b487fb5360dd1e5ef840c"),
    "internal_id" : 1,
    "created_at" : ISODate("2015-07-14T10:08:38.994Z"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2016-01-10T00:35:19.748Z"),
    "ad_account_id" : 1,
    "updated_time" : "2013-08-05T04:48:49-0700",
    "created_time" : "2013-08-05T04:46:35-0700",
    "name" : "Sale1",
    "daily": [
                 {"clicks": 5000, "date": "2015-04-16"},
                 {"clicks": 5100, "date": "2015-04-17"},
                 {"clicks": 5030, "date": "2015-04-20"}
             ]
    "custom_tags" : {
        "Event" : {
            "name" : "Clicks"
        },
        "Objective" : {
            "name" : "Sale"
        },
        "Image" : {
            "name" : "43c3fe7b262cde5f476ed303e472c65a"
        },
        "Goal" : {
            "name" : "10"
        },
        "Type" : {
             "name" : "None"
        },
        "Call To Action" : {
             "name" : "None",
        },
        "Landing Pages" : {
            "name" : "www.google.com",
    }
}
```

I am trying to group individual documents by `internal_id` to find the aggregate sum of clicks from say `2015-04-15` to `2015-04-21` using the `aggregate` method.

In pymongo, when I try to do an `aggregate` using just `$project` on `internal_id`, I get the results, but when I try to `$project` `custom_tags` fields, I get the following error:

```
OperationFailure: Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort.
Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.
```

Following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069601/how-to-aggregate-on-huge-array-in-mongodb), I even changed my aggregate function to `list(collection._get_collection().aggregate(mongo_query["pipeline"], allowDiskUse=True))`. But this still keeps throwing the earlier error.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this link:
[Can't get allowDiskUse:True to work with pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272699/cant-get-allowdiskusetrue-to-work-with-pymongo)

This Works for me:

```
someSampleList= db.collectionName.aggregate(pipeline, allowDiskUse=True)
```

Where

```
pipeline = [
    {'$sort': {'sortField': 1}},
    {'$group': {'_id': '$distinctField'}}, 
    {'$limit': 20000}]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with that:

list(collection._get_collection().aggregate(mongo_query["pipeline"], {allowDiskUse : true}))

Comment: Your answer is not compliant to python. allowDiskUse and true are not defined